# Tweepy is not running on anaconda jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda, tweepy, conda-forge

I have installed tweepy on anaconda promptconda install -c conda-forge tweepy  but I received below error any idea ?

```
 import tweepy
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns) 
File "<ipython-input-1-f5e4f2180e08>", line 1, in <module> import tweepy 
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\__init__.py", line 17, in <module> from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener 
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 358 def _start(self, async): 
                                                                                                    ^ 
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This GitHub issue has the answer: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017#issuecomment-387703653

Essentially, `async` is a reserved keyword in Python 3.7 and cannot be used as a function argument. Quoting the relevant part of the issue:

> Okay found the solution. Apparently async cannot be used as an
>   argument name in Python 3.7 So open streaming.py and replace #async
>   with async_ it fixed the error for me.

Comment: you mean that   for def _start(self, async) will be   def _start(self, async_it) right?

Comment: @tfirinci as the error is in line 358, you should start looking from that line.

Comment: @AviThour If you quote from the github issue, please indicate that it is a quote and use the blockquote formatting (start the line with `>`)

Comment: @darthbith thanks for the tip, added into the answer.